# zooming gameObject AND children with RectTransform.sizeDelta

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've got a game object in Unity which is basically composed of UI image with UI texts on it.
I'm trying to zoom it with the property size delta of the RectTransform component of the whole object.

```
RectTransform rect = zoomCard.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(300, 400);
```

It kinda works, but halfway:
the game object is zoomed, but its children (the textUI childs) do not kept the same position while zoomed..

Is there a way to get around this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if you ever have this problem :
It's related to the anchors of your gameObject, you know the little white triangles making a kind of cross in front of your gameObject. These are the most important, when you place perfectly your label or whatever on your gameObject, make sure to drag those triangles at the 4 corners of your lable, and it will be resized along your parent gameObject.

Answer (score 0):

You must zomming it with `transform.localScale` property. It changes whole transform tree including children. `RectTransform.sizeDelta` changes only gameobject itself.